# Getting these messages in the ubuntu logs. What do they mean?

Tags: nvidia, gnome, pulseaudio

I am a new Ubuntu user. I am getting these messages when i open logs of my system. My system works perfectly normal. Are they anything to worry about?

```
17:55:39 pulseaudio: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EB_06_EF_7C_94_74/sep1/fd0 Volume failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property 'Volume'

17:55:07 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

17:55:07 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

17:55:05 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

17:55:01 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

17:54:54 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

17:54:54 systemd: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.

17:54:50 kernel: 
17:54:50 kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

Comment: It's not clear from your post if the errors appear only a single time, or if they persist - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general rule of thumb when it comes to log messages:

1. If you get an error message a single or few times, but the system appears to be working normally, then it's probably nothing to worry about.
2. If the same error message keep appearing over and over (like every minute), then you should definitely investigate the problem.

It's unfortunately not possible to explain the meaning of all error messages, but generally if something fails once, it will try again and most probably succeed - hence no reason to be worried about single messages.

Repeated error messages, on the other hand, is a symptom of an underlying (and probably more serious) error that persists, and should be handled accordingly.

Comment: If it's only at boot time, I'd say they are safe to ignore. If you experience any particular issue, you can use these messages to troubleshoot. But for now, you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my only concern was because these exact same messages come in the logs after every boot so i was wondering if anything was wrong. Though my system works perfectly fine.

Comment: okay thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

> `gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed`

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1968907), it should be fixed in an upcoming release (not yet available at the time of this answer).

The bug report does confirm that everything appears to be working normally, regardless of the messages.

Also see the associated [commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-session/-/commit/0349a77ad875b78b37700918308fc37b477777ae) and the [merge request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-session/-/merge_requests/83).